# what happens in public Node head=null; while implementing linked lists with java?

Tags: java

```
  public class Node {
        public int data;
        public Node next;
        public Node(){
            data=0;
            next=null;
        }
        public Node(int x){
            data=x;
            next=null;
        }
    }
```

The above code is the class Node, where it contains `data` and `next` variables.
Using this class observe the following code:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList {
public Node head=null;
public  void insert_at_head(int x){
    Node newnode=new Node(x);
    if(head==null){
        head=newnode;
    }
    else{
        newnode.next=head;
        head=newnode;
    }
}
```

At line 2 head of type Node is initialized to `null`. What is actually happening here? Is it equal to initializing `head.data` and `head.next` to `null`?

Comment: Just for the record: that assignment next=null is actually pointless - `null` is the default value that any reference type object has initially. Then: read about java naming conventions. You dont use "_" in method names - it is only for SOME_CONSTANT.

Comment: Since `Node.next` is initialized to `null`, the entire conditional can be eliminated, because the end result of calling `insert_at_head` is going to be the same no matter what branch the code takes. The code below will perform the same operation without a conditional:

`public  void insert_at_head(int x){
        Node newnode=new Node(x);
        newnode.next=head;
        head=newnode;
    }`